# How do I use jq to pull the newest HUE Scene from the JSON dump?

Tags: json, jq, chronological

I am trying to use jq to find the ID of a hue scene when I pass the scene name.  The problem is if I update the scene it makes another scene with a new ID assigned to it.  So as I make changes to the scene more than one result returns.  How Do I find the newest scene?  I see there is an object that is lastupdated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
curl -s ${BASEURL}/scenes/ | /usr/local/bin/jq -r -e --arg SCENENAME "${SCENENAME}" '. as $object | keys[] | select($object[.].name == $SCENENAME)'
```

Here is what the json output looks like:

```
  "FUX9A2m4LcuF6YG": {
    "name": "KitchenDay",
    "lights": [
      "6",
      "7",
      "10",
      "11"
    ],
    "owner": "43594f081bb6d23e9ccd254927fa47",
    "recycle": true,
    "locked": false,
    "appdata": {},
    "picture": "",
    "lastupdated": "2018-02-25T03:35:57",
    "version": 2   }
```

Comment: Please show the JSON produced by the curl command, the value of SCENENAME, and the expected output. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry I just realized you asked for the value of SCENENAME.  In my exmample I used KitchenDay.  I want to get the key of the scene with the newest lastupdated value.  Right now my code returns the key of any entry that matches name == KitchenDay.

Answer (score 1):

In this response, I'll assume the following input, which seems to capture the essence of the problem:

```
{
  "FUX9A2m4LcuF6YG": {
    "name": "KitchenDay",
    "lastupdated": "2018-02-25T03:35:57"
  },
  "later": {
    "name": "KitchenNight",
    "lastupdated": "2018-02-25T23:35:57"
  }
}
```

With that as input, the following filter:

```
to_entries | [max_by(.value.lastupdated)] | from_entries
```

produces:

```
{
  "later": {
    "name": "KitchenNight",
    "lastupdated": "2018-02-25T23:35:57"
  }
}
```

The key here is that the max of the "lastupdated" field corresponds to the most recent time.

If you just want the key name, you could instead write:

```
to_entries | max_by(.value.lastupdated) | .key
```

Comment: So my code will look like this?  
`curl -s ${BASEURL}/scenes/ | /usr/local/bin/jq -r -e --arg SCENENAME "${SCENENAME}" '. as $object | keys[] | select($object[.].name == $SCENENAME) | to_entries | [max_by(.value.lastupdated)] | from_entries'`

Because that returns this message.
`jq: error (at <stdin>:0): string ("FUX9A2m4Lc...) has no keys`

That string is the ID which is also the key.  Any advice?